# Magento url rewrite using htaccess

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I have a custom cms page like "www.example.com/brand-productlist?brand-id=147" .I need the url like "www.example.com/brand-productlist/147" using htaccess in magento 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `URL Key` in page edit (no need to use htaccess)

[image]

UPDATE:
I think default routes are created automatically:

[image]

The url-key is generated based on title of page.

Comment: I can't use url key every time the parameter will change like ""www.example.com/brand-productlist?brand-id=148" i need the url like ""www.example.com/brand-productlist/148" for seo purpose.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take a look.